# how to get webbrowser module for python 3.6 using pip ?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, python-webbrowser

C:\Users\vipul>pip install webbrowser
Collecting webbrowser
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement webbrowser (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for webbrowser

whenever I try to install I get this error

Comment: are you using a packaged python 3 distribution like Entware, openwrt, ... ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

webbrowser is part of the python standard library, you don't have to install a separate package to use it because it comes bundled with your python installation.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/webbrowser.html), you can use it from the command line as follows:

```
python -m webbrowser -t "http://www.python.org"
```

Or from your own scripts:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://www.python.org')
```